# laravel how to use query builder DB::table(..) with DB::connection()

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 databases defined in config/databases, mysql and mysql2
The default connection is mysql

I need to get this data from mysql2

```
$programs=DB::table('node')->where('type', 'Programs')->get();
```

The docs tell me I can change the connection using

```
$programs=DB::connection('mysql2')->select(...)
```

which would let me run a sql statement to get an array for $programs. 
But I am wondering if there is a way to combine the 2 statements i.e. use query builder on specific db::connection.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You should use:

```
$programs=DB::connection('mysql2')->table('node')->where('type', 'Programs')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you @Phil for asking & thank you Marcin Nabiałek for the answer

Comment: It's enough tu put the name of the new connection, or it has to be with `config(database.connections.mysql2')` ?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "table" does not exist LINE 1: select * from "table" where "usuario" = $1 ^ (SQL: select * from "table" where "user" = username)